# Change settings of a multicolumn/multirow table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I just have a little question. I need to draw a payoff-matrix. I already have one, but I had to make some changes there. The are still some things I like to improve but I was not able to do so far.

[image]

Is there a way to delete the lines I have mentioned on the picture above? And is it also to get the same width for the cells? I hope you see what I mean

Thank you for your help!!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} % Seitenlayout
%headsep=7mm, footskip= 7mm
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} % Inhaltsverzeichnis in Times

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument
\usepackage{csquotes}             % Apostroph-Zeichen

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Zeilenabstand 

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % Mathematik
\usepackage{MnSymbol} % Underbrace

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Graph

\usepackage{multirow,array} % Auszahlungsmatrix
\usepackage{arydshln}          % vertikale und horizontale Linien in Tabelle
\dashlinegap=1pt                   % gestrichelte Linie in Tabelle

\usepackage{tikz}             % Auszahlungsmatrix

\usepackage{acronym}     % Sonstiges
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % Sonstiges

\usepackage{float} % Positionierung von Grafiken

\usepackage{caption}                 % Abbildungen/Tabellen beschriften
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=15pt} % Caption weiter unter setzen

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c|}}
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Spieler 2} \\
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &  & $y$ & $1-y$ \\ \cline{4-5}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &  & $s_{21} $ & $s_{22}$ \\ \cline{3-5}
      \multirow{2}*{Spieler 1} 
      & $x$ & $s_{11}$ & $1$ & $-1$ \\ \cline{3-5}
      & $1-x$ & $s_{12}$ & $-1$ & $1$ \\ \cline{3-5}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes were as follows:

1. `{c*{4}{c|}}` instead of `{*{5}{c|}}` to eliminate the left-most unwanted vertical line
2. Use of 1-column multicolumns on top row, to eliminate the vertical lines in that row.
3. Placing the wide `1-y` into a zero width `\makebox`, so that its excess width would not affect the overall column width.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} % Seitenlayout
%headsep=7mm, footskip= 7mm
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} % Inhaltsverzeichnis in Times

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument
\usepackage{csquotes}             % Apostroph-Zeichen

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Zeilenabstand 

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % Mathematik
\usepackage{MnSymbol} % Underbrace

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Graph

\usepackage{multirow,array} % Auszahlungsmatrix
\usepackage{arydshln}          % vertikale und horizontale Linien in Tabelle
\dashlinegap=1pt                   % gestrichelte Linie in Tabelle

\usepackage{tikz}             % Auszahlungsmatrix

\usepackage{acronym}     % Sonstiges
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % Sonstiges

\usepackage{float} % Positionierung von Grafiken

\usepackage{caption}                 % Abbildungen/Tabellen beschriften
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=15pt} % Caption weiter unter setzen

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
    \begin{tabular}{c*{4}{c|}}
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Spieler 2} \\
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{$1-y$}} \\ \cline{4-5}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &  & $s_{21} $ & $s_{22}$ \\ \cline{3-5}
      \multirow{2}*{Spieler 1} 
      & $x$ & $s_{11}$ & $1$ & $-1$ \\ \cline{3-5}
      & $1-x$ & $s_{12}$ & $-1$ & $1$ \\ \cline{3-5}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} % Seitenlayout
%headsep=7mm, footskip= 7mm
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} % Inhaltsverzeichnis in Times

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument
\usepackage{csquotes}             % Apostroph-Zeichen

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Zeilenabstand 

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % Mathematik
\usepackage{MnSymbol} % Underbrace

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Graph

\usepackage{multirow,array} % Auszahlungsmatrix
\usepackage{arydshln}          % vertikale und horizontale Linien in Tabelle
\dashlinegap=1pt                   % gestrichelte Linie in Tabelle

\usepackage{tikz}             % Auszahlungsmatrix

\usepackage{acronym}     % Sonstiges
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % Sonstiges

\usepackage{float} % Positionierung von Grafiken

\usepackage{caption}                 % Abbildungen/Tabellen beschriften
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=15pt} % Caption weiter unter setzen

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4mm}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Spieler 2} \\
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$1-y$} \\ \cline{4-5}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &  & $s_{21} $ & $s_{22}$ \\ \cline{3-5}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}*{Spieler 1}} 
      & $x$ & $s_{11}$ & $1$ & $-1$ \\ \cline{3-5}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& $1-x$ & $s_{12}$ & $-1$ & $1$ \\ \cline{3-5}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```